# Rich content front-ends/jQueryUI replacement

Tags: javascript, frontend

I've been going around in circles for days on this. I've got a (conceptually) simple website, which is all Javascript/Ajax at the front end, with a minimal amount of hand-written HTML, and lots of C++ on the server. The user basically needs to see a few menus, and fill in a few forms, and they get back pretty tables.

My problem is the actual UI front-end. This is for a sports club, and is not a commercial site, so it doesn't have to be that good. I've been using jQueryUI (there's some jQuery in the JS). I'm using tabs and dialogs, and it's all a bit clunky. I now want to add a couple of horizontal menus, and jQueryUI doesn't do this (there's [menubar](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/38666403/Menubar), on a code branch, but it's unfinished and development stopped 6 months ago). I also want to integrate dokuwiki if possible, which is php. I don't have to support old browsers.

Question: can anyone recommend a lightweight rich content front-end to replace jQueryUI, that will get me going quickly? I can spend a little on something commercial as long as I can quickly prototype without paying anything. A CMS would be Ok - I have some Joomla experience, but I really don't want to write any modules just to get my own JS and a wiki into the site.

Oh - and please suggest something quickly, before the question is closed as pointless and irrelevant... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of examples.
Twitter bootstrap or flat ui

Comment: Thx - I'd never heard of Bootstrap, but it seems to be everywhere, and I've prototyped quickly in it. Looks good.